# JavaFX Not Able to Start From Non-FX Project In NetBeans Using Start

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, javafx-2

The problem I'm having is that when I create a new JavaFX project in NetBeans the main method is ignored, and somehow start() is somehow called and everything is just fine, but any time I try to call start I wind up with an exception. The class I used:

```
public final class JFXDriver extends Application {

public JFXDriver() {
    Application.launch();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

I've attempted to start it using the constructor, but it fails (Throws an Exception) for some reason saying that it is being called more than once, which should be impossible because I've constructed this class from a main method with only the `new JFXDriver();` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong in the code. You should not call launch in your constructor. You should call it in your main and pass the name of the class that extends Application.

This causes the system to call init and then start and thus begins the lifecycle of your applicaton. For a more detailed explanation have a look here: http://codelatte.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/getting-started-with-javafx-hello-world-2/

Are you attempting a Swing and FX interop ?

Comment: No, I was just curious about how to run it from a normal application instead of having to create a new JavaFX project each time I wanted to try something new. Although I do have plans to attempt a Swing and FX program together.

Comment: Well... I will be doing a blog post about Swing FX interop. Will notify you when done.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've found a solution to the problem. I added:

```
public static void start() {
    Application.launch();
}
```

and took out the call to Application.launch() in the constructor. This approach worked. I guess that the JavaFX thread created its own instance of the class leading to the Application.launch() being called more than once. Interestingly, without the one application limit, I wonder if this would have led to a StackOverflowException due to the recursive nature of the call.